# Integrating Solr with Nutch issue

Tags: solr, nutch

I am following a tutorial from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). i have got solr and nutch installed separately and they are both working all fine. The problem comes when i have to integrate them. From the earlier posts on this site i learned that there could some issue with the schema files. As mentioned in the tut i copied the schema.xml of nutch to the schema.xml of solr and restarted the solr. solr stoped because of configuration issues. So i simply copied the  contents of each file into the other along with the existing content. Now (and previously as well) i get this error:

```
Indexer: starting at 2014-08-05 11:10:21
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

Can someone suggest what should be done?
I am using apache-nutch-1.8 and solr-4.9.0
 Here is how my hadoop.log file looks like:

```
2014-08-05 12:50:05,032 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: starting at 2014-08-05 12:50:05
2014-08-05 12:50:05,033 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: crawlDb: -dir/crawldb
2014-08-05 12:50:05,033 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: urlDir: urls
.
.
.
.
.
2014-08-05 13:04:21,255 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 1 documents
2014-08-05 13:04:21,286 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1310160376_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://my-solr-url:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:155)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:118)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)
2014-08-05 13:04:21,544 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)

2014-08-05 13:10:37,855 INFO  crawl.Injector - Injector: starting at 2014-08-05 13:10:37
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks @JayeshBhoyar i have added the logs. If you can really help, it would be highly appeciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be because of some versioning differences the tutorial suggested to copy the conf/schema.xml whereas in this particular version of solr, the file schema-solr4.xml was supposed to be copied followed by addition of : `<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>` in line no 351. Restart the solr by `java -jar start.jar` and it works all normal! Hope this helps someone!